# Pymongo: Get all keys and it's data type from collection

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I want to get all keys including the nested ones with their data types in Python.

```
{ "_id" : "123", "name": "dona", "age": 27, "sex": "F", "foo":{"bar": "lol", "bar2":{"foo2" : "l1"}}
```

For the above document I want to get the following output.

```
[ "_id", "name", "age", "sex", "foo.bar", "foo.bar2.foo2"]
```

If I can get these keys in a dictionary with their respective data-types that would be great.

Fetching all the documents and iterating over them to get the unique keys and their data types is I believe not a very optimal way to do this. Any other way would be appreciated.